# Can i install Windows 10 dual boot Ubuntu correctly via Linux "install alongside" option?

Tags: linux, windows, multi-boot, operating-systems

I have Ubuntu 16.04 installed without important data. I want to have **Ubuntu 16.04 dual boot Windows 10**. I read that doing this dual boot is better from windows. I want to install Windows 10 with erasing Ubuntu and then install Ubuntu 16.04 with "*install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10*" option. My question is: **is it correctly making dual boot this way?**

Comment: There is no "incorrect" way to dual boot considering there is only one method to achieve it.  You do understand Ubuntu 16.04 is not supported, is extremely out of date, you should be using Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: @Ramhound I tried 18.04 but this version is not good for me

Comment: You have not really explained where in the process you are stuck.  It's extremely hard to install Windows and Ubuntu on the same HDD incorrectly.  If you install both of them correctly.

Comment: @Ramhound Ubuntu 16.04 is a LTS and supported until 2021.

Comment: @VladGavriuk First of all understand UEFI mode and its requirements, assuming you already understand partitioning (if not, start there). Then read this https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi and update your question with reference to this guide in case you're stuck at some point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. I successfully installed **Ubuntu 18.04 LTS** dual boot **Windows 8.1**.
You need to install Windows first and then install Ubuntu or other Linux distribution with "*install Ubuntu alongside* Windows" option.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, but do not forget to enable legacy boot and disable fast boot in your BIOS otherwise windows will kick in before Linux.

Comment: The "kick" can be adjusted in grub configuration.